# How to use PubSub Push subscriptions with VPC Service Controls?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

Google Cloud VPC Service Control limitations mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products) states:

- In projects protected by a service perimeter, new push subscriptions cannot be created.
- Pub/Sub push subscriptions created prior to the service perimeter will not be blocked.

**Questions**

**1.** Does this mean that in order to use PubSub Push subscriptions with VPC Service control one has to:

- Create a push subscription first and then
- Define the VPC service perimeter

**2.** Is this a Google recommended secure way to create use PubSub push subscriptions with VPC Service control?

**3.** Or is Google recommendation to completely avoid using PubSub push subscriptions with VPC Service Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your perimeter, you need to manage all the communication. An external push is an unmanaged event and not compliant with the VPC SC.

That's why, you can't create a push subscription when the perimeter is set: it's not secure.

However, to not break your current project and architecture, Google doesn't delete/deactivate the existing push subscriptions that continue to work as before.

---

So now, because you need to manage all the connexion of your VPC SC, the correct pattern is to use a pull subscription to initiate a communication from the VPC SC to PubSub subscription and then to get the message inside the perimeter.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere. The way I understand your response is the Google recommended mechanism is to use PubSub Pull subscriptions when using VPC Service control. Also avoid using Push subscriptions with VPC Service Controls altogether wherever possible - unless it breaks existing design/component and has no other alternative.

Comment: Correct, your summary is better than my bad english ;)

Comment: Accepting this answer. Your English is at least good as mine - if not better:-)